# Create ItemTemplate for ListBox in code-beind in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, styles, itemtemplate

I'm trying to create an ItemTemplate for a ListBox programmatically but it doesn't work. I know in XAML I can have something like:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox" BorderThickness="0" Margin="6" Height="400">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Margin="0" Background="Red" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

But when I'm trying to have the above result programmatically I face a problem which is binding the `TextBox.TextProperty`:

```
var textblock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));

// Setting some properties
textblock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, ??);
var template = new ControlTemplate(typeof(ListBoxItem));
template.VisualTree = textblock;
```

Please help me on this issue. I couldn't find anything on the web about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try use dot `.` in  Binding, this is the equivalent of `{Binding}`.

Example:

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MainWindow"
        ...
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">

    <ListBox Name="MyListBox" ... />
</Window>
```

`Code-behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBlockFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        textBlockFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding(".")); // Here
        textBlockFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
        textBlockFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Wheat);
        textBlockFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.FontSizeProperty, 18.0);

        var template = new DataTemplate();            
        template.VisualTree = textBlockFactory;

        MyListBox.ItemTemplate = template;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now what if I want to bind the ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection and bind the TextBlockFactory to the DisplayMemberPath? I mean could you provide me an approach so that I can use the template either with or without ItemsSource binding to an ObservableCollection?

Comment: @user3530012: Of course I can, maybe, but you should create a new question. I can not answer of your newly questions in the comments.

Comment: I asked it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081311/create-itemtemplate-for-listbox-in-code-behind-in-wpf-part-ii

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, by binding the "listbox" with ItemsSource and specify the datatemplate below like if you want to bind name then just write {Binding Name}**

```
 <ListBox x:Name="listbox" BorderThickness="0" Margin="6" Height="400" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0" Background="Red" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```